# Accessing a com.tridion.user.User object without a page context?

Tags: content-delivery, 2013

I have a tricky one for the hardcore Tridion CD people here...

I want to load and enrich a `User`'s `CustomerCharacteristics` from an Ambient Data Cartridge, but been struggling to find a way to load/find this object.

The correct way of loading a user is to use:

```java
JSPPage jspPage = new JSPPage(pageContext, "tcm:1-2-64");
User user = jspPage.getUser();
```

But in the context of a cartridge I am running *before* the page, and I don't have access to the [pageContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html) object. Or do I?

Does anyone know a way to get the PageContext object for a page from a filter? And would there be an easy-ish way to make this object available to a Cartridge?

Comment: I remember having to create a `PageContext` myself once, but that was a long time ago, and there I really needed it for the `Out` (or `JspWriter`) property. You might want to decompile `JSPPage.getUser()` and see what is all done in there and see if you can get to that without a `PageContext` or `JSPPage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context is not available in a Cartridge or ADF because there are different implementations in .Net and Java for it and ADF should be technology agnostic.

What about using this class.

```
User user = UserManager.CheckUser(presentationId, userId, login);
```

This API does not need the context, now, how to get the userId, if it is an existing user, it will be stored in the WAI cookie, I think you can use a Cookie claim to read it or read it in a previous Filter/Http Module and put it in the claim store.

Comment: This would probably work, yes, but I'd have to determine the contact ID or create a new one if I couldn't, which could be tricky. Wonder how it would react if the user doesn't exist? I'll give it a try

Comment: I got it to work. I'll mark your answer as correct and post the code somewhere for anyone else trying the same.

Comment: Code Available here: https://github.com/NunoLinhares/TridionContextEngine/tree/master/com/sdl/tridion/context/personalization