# Ambient Data Framework Documentation for SDL Tridion 2011

Tags: ambient-data-framework

As a follow-up to my last ADF question ([Adding a Date option to Session Footprint](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/3789/46)), I'm looking to learn how to set up cartridges on an SDL Tridion 2011 environment.

I can follow [Jaime's post for 2013](http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.com/2013/10/managing-claims-and-their-scope-in-sdl.html) up through installation, but get the following when using his SetClaim.aspx example:

```
CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Runtime' does not exist in the namespace 'Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

SetClaim.aspx's code-behind has:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData;

public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private readonly int maxSize = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        AmbientDataContext.CurrentClaimStore.Put(new Uri("taf:claim:jaimesideas:blogurl"), "http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.com", Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Runtime.ClaimType.Normal);
        String claim = AmbientDataContext.CurrentClaimStore.Get<String>(new Uri("taf:claim:jaimesideas:blogurl"));
        ClaimStore cs = AmbientDataContext.CurrentClaimStore;
        if (cs != null)
        {
            foreach (var c in cs.GetAll())
            {
                Response.Write(string.Format("{0} - {1}<br/>", c.Key, c.Value));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

`Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Runtime` is available in the 2013 documentation, but I don't see the `AmbientData` namespace mentioned in the `SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 Content Delivery ASP.NET API` .chm documentation.

**I'm looking for help on the right namespace and methods to use for cartridges for a 2011 cartridge example or clarification on what documentation to check.**

*Or let me know if we're only supposed to do custom cartridges on 2013 or later.* :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have the 2011 .Net API handy, but I never used this third parameter to the Put method. Try the following:

```
AmbientDataContext.CurrentClaimStore.Put(new Uri("taf:claim:myclaim"), "claimvalue");
```

You can use custom cartridges with Tridion 2011.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The two-parameter method worked and my fault for not checking the API with intellisense (duh).

Answer (score 3):

Like Philippe said, in Tridion 2011 you can't use the third parameter like that.

```
AmbientDataContext.CurrentClaimStore.Put(new Uri("taf:claim:jaimesideas:blogurl"), "http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.com", Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Runtime.ClaimType.Normal);
```

Tridion 2011 SP1 has

- Claimstore.Put(Uri, Object)
- Claimstore.Put(Uri, Object, Boolean)

Tridion 2013 GA has

- Claimstore.Put(Uri, Object)
- Claimstore.Put(Uri, Object, Boolean) -> marked Obsolete
- Claimstore.Put(Uri, Object, ClaimType) -> new  in Tridion 2013

The third parameter, ClaimType is in the Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Runtime namespace which caused the confusion. The fun thing about this ClaimType is that we now can set immutable and readonly claims.