# Adding a Claim After Detecting an Existing Claim

Tags: experience-manager, ambient-data-framework

I'm following up on [Adding a Date option to Session Footprint](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/3789/46) and [Ambient Data Framework Documentation for SDL Tridion 2011](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/3804/46).

Specifically I'm trying to follow [this excellent answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/3799/46) (thanks much, Peter!).

My setup has SDL Tridion 2011 (with SmartTarget), Fredhopper, and Experience Manager with Session Preview as seen in `cd_ambient_conf.xml`:

```
<Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml"/>
<Cartridge File="footprint_cartridge_conf.xml"/>
<Cartridge File="date_cartridge.xml"/><!-- custom -->       
<Cartridge File="smarttarget_cartridge_conf.xml"/>
```

I'm able to add new claims with a custom XPM Footprint setting and through the following.

```
public class DateWebClaimProcessor extends AbstractClaimProcessor {

    @Override
    public void onRequestStart(ClaimStore claimStore)
        throws AmbientDataException {
            try {

            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

            Date today = new Date();
            claimStore.put(new URI("fh:today:date"), today);

            if (claimStore.contains(new URI("fh:user:date")))
                {
                // won't run -- claim processor currently runs out of order, maybe?
                String claimdate = claimStore.get(new URI("fh:user:date")).toString();

                Date date = formatter.parse(claimdate);
                claimStore.put(new URI("fh:converted:date"), date);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new AmbientDataException(ex);
            }
    }
```

After choosing a specific footprint date and using the [ClaimStore page example](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/AmbientDataFrameworkTestPage) I have:

> **fh:today:date** 12/5/2013 12:53:12 AM (added by above)
>
> **fh:user:date**  2012-11-01T00:00:00 (added by Footprint setting)

But I don't get `fh:converted:date`. I think I need to confirm the order of my cartridges and see that the [Order of execution for ADF cartridges](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/3113/46) is (partly?) based on `OutputClaim` and `InputClaim` definitions in Cartridges.

**How can I tell what order Session Preview, SmartTarget, and the Footprint run?** Is there an expected order or should I check the logs? I'm trying to visual [this diagram](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_27C302257F4F476DB71EA82D5E3B20EF) but with XPM, ST, and FH. :-)

My custom footprint isn't really in the `footprint_cartridge_conf.xml` as an `OutputClaim` (in `footprint_cartridge.jar`), so maybe I'm on the wrong track?

*Functionally, I'm trying to get a date set in the footprint recognized by SmartTarget to get date-based campaigns to show in XPM.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following, it worked for me:

In your cartridge configuration xml e.g. `date_cartridge.xml`

```
<ClaimDefinition Uri="fh:user:date" Scope="SESSION" Description="website visit date within the context." />
```

...

```
<ClaimProcessorDefinition Uri="taf:pe:claimprocessor:context:date"
        ImplementationClass="com.tridion.extensions.ambientdata.DateClaimProcessor"
        Description="Sets the website visit Date">
  <RequestStart>
    <InputClaims>
        <ClaimDefinition Uri="taf:claim:context:date" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
      <ClaimDefinition Uri="fh:user:date" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </RequestStart>
</ClaimProcessorDefinition>
```

Here is the Claim Processor class `DateClaimProcessor.java`

```
package com.tridion.extensions.ambientdata;

import java.net.URI;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.tridion.ambientdata.AmbientDataException;
import com.tridion.ambientdata.claimstore.ClaimStore;
import com.tridion.ambientdata.claimstore.ClaimType;
import com.tridion.ambientdata.processing.AbstractClaimProcessor;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateClaimProcessor extends AbstractClaimProcessor {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DateClaimProcessor.class);    
public static final String DATE_CLAIM_URI = "fh:user:date";
    public static final String CONTEXT_DATE_CLAIM_URI = "taf:claim:context:date";
public static final URI DATE_URI = URI.create(DATE_CLAIM_URI);
    public static final URI CONTEXT_DATE_URI = URI.create(CONTEXT_DATE_CLAIM_URI);

public DateClaimProcessor() {
    log.debug("DateClaimProcessor: called");
}

@Override
public void onRequestStart(ClaimStore claimStore) throws AmbientDataException {
    log.debug("DateClaimProcessor.onRequestStart: Called");

            if(claimStore.contains(CONTEXT_DATE_URI))
            {
                log.debug("DateClaimProcessor ClaimStore contains " + CONTEXT_DATE_CLAIM_URI);
                //get the date claim and set it as Date object instead of string
                String dateString = claimStore.get(CONTEXT_DATE_URI).toString();
                if(dateString!=null)
                {
                    log.debug("DateClaimProcessor date=" + dateString);
                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
                    Date date =null;
                   try{
                    date = df.parse(dateString);
                   }
                   catch(Exception e)
                   {
                       log.error("DateClaimProcessor error - " + e.getMessage());
                   }
                    if(date!=null)
                    {                            
                        log.debug("DateClaimProcessor adding fh:user:date as date object=" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(date));
                        claimStore.put(DATE_URI, date);
                    }
                }
            }
}
}
```

Set the custom claim in `SiteEditModel.config`:

```
<footprint ID="visitDate" claimUri="taf:claim:context:date" >
            <title>
                <value lang="1033">Visit Date</value>
            </title>
            <description>
                <value>Select a date for viewing the website as it would look on that date.</value>
            </description>
            <settings>
                <isMandatory>true</isMandatory>
            </settings>                                           
        </footprint>
```

Set the corresponding footprint in `SiteEditEditor.config` (as you did before):

```
<footprint ID="visitDate" controlID="FootprintDate" Icon="calendar"/>
```

This basically uses a custom date claim which is set by the XPM footprint, and if that claim exists the cartridge actually creates the `fh:user:date` claim as a date object so it gets recognized by FH properly.

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed a couple of problems with this approach:

1. You should use full URIs in the Claim Store (which are then transformed using the prefixes in SmartTarget). For instance, you might use a URI like "taf:claim:ambientdata:datecartridge:user:date" and configure "fh" as the prefix for "taf:claim:ambientdata:datecartridge" in smarttarget_conf.xml. This isn't stopping it from working, I just wanted to point out the recommended naming convention.
2. I didn't notice that you were on version which has this functionality in a cartridge (in newer versions it's in the framework itself). You can force your cartridge to run after the footprint cartridge, by setting one of its output claims (for instance 'taf:claim:ambientdata:footprintcartridge:acceptlanguage') as an input claim to your cartridge.

You cannot rely on the order of the cartridges except through this means of dependency management. I don't believe the order of cartridges is explicitly logged anywhere, but likely each cartridge would log something so you can see the order that way.

Comment: Ah, so the dependency doesn't need to be a specific claim. I missed that point. Thanks for the naming convention clarification, that was my next question. I knew enough to at least change Jaime's "`jsa:`" prefix. :-)