# Why is new Footprint not showing up in Footprint set

Tags: experience-manager

I am trying to add a new item to my Footprint Set in XPM with a new Footprint, i.e. add a new item to the list in the image below:
[image: Footprint Set]

I've updated `SiteEditEditor.config` file with my Footprint, and the `SiteEditModel.config` with the available options for the Footprint as per the SDLLive documentation (http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-E169F5F2-3A34-422E-8566-A6A620BB77C9, login required).

I have saved my files and restarted IIS (iisreset).  I've also refreshed my browser (Chrome), also tried restarting the browser.  However, the new Footprint just doesn't show up in my list.  I believe my syntax is correct.  What could be the issue?

BTW, I know the answer, and using this Q as a way to document for others...

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Saw the same with: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/3789/46.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Nickoli says it is a browser caching issue. Proceed as follows:

1. Update *SiteEditEditor.config*
2. Update *SiteEditModel.config*
3. Clear the browser cache (reloading the browser is not enough, you really need to clear the history.

Restarting IIS is not necessary.

I believe you could increase the version number somewhere in the CME config to force all browsers to load all the CME GUI resources again, including this footprint set configuration. I did not try that but I think you should use it to roll out the changes to all users.

Answer (score 8):

If you are sure that the syntax in the config files is correct, then this is most likely a browser cache issue.  Actually, this was exactly the issue as per my question above.  Once the browser history and data was cleared, the new custom Footprint was loaded in the GUI.   As basic as this issue sounds, this did take some additional time to troubleshoot. Hope it helps the next person.

[image]